# Best practices for lazy loading objects from server

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, client-server, datasource

I have a question about program architecture.
I often face the following problem:

Let's say we have an array of objects on our server. One object consists of a brief description (let's call it `description`) and a heavy `fullData`.
We have a client application, which downloads a list of objects with `description` only. And when user selects one item in a list, `fullData` for this item is loaded.

I usually implement some sort of a `dataSource` object, which loads a list of elements with `descriptions`s.  But then we have to get `fullData` from server.

I usually do it like this: implement a method like `fetchFullDataForObject(MyObject object)` (pseudocode) in `DataSource`.

The problem is that in this case objects become dependent on the dataSource (if we want to access object's `fullData`, we either have to check if it's `null` and call `fetchFullData` ourselves, or implicitly call it inside the Object (in this case object has to hold reference to the dataSource which it belongs to, I implemented this option in pseudocode below)). In both cases we have to hold reference to the `dataSource`.
Another option is to hold a code for fetching `fullData` inside an Objects class. But in this case Object contains logic for client-server interaction. It doesn't look like a good practice to me.

**What are the best practices for such situations? Whose responsibility downloading the `fullData` is?** May be there is some common design pattern which is used in such cases?

I implemented one of possible options below. Since it is not specific (to my mind) to the development language, I wrote it in pseudocode.

```
//pseudocode
class Object
{
    private String description;
    private Data fullData = null;
    DataSource dataSource;

    public Object(String description, DataSource dataSource)
    {
        this.description = description;
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
    }

    public String getDescription()
    {
        return this.description;
    }

    public Data getFullData()
    {
        if (fullData == null)
            this.dataSource.fetchFullDataForObject(this); //one of possible options
        return fullData;
    }
};

class DataSource
{
    private List<Object>  objects = null;
    private void loadItemsFromServer(); //loads objects (without fullData) and saves them to the "objects" list

    public List<Object> getObjects()
    {
        if (objects == null)
            loadItemsFromServer();
        return objects;
    }

    public void fetchFullDataForObject(Object object);
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right that holding reference from the `Object` to the `dataSource` isn't a good practice because:

- Your `dataSource` object is similar to [Repository](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html) pattern implementation.
- Your `Object` is similar to Domain Entity.

It is better to split Data Access and Domain Model.

So, you have the following options:

1. You can extract `IDataSource` interface and put it in your Domain Model. And its implementation `DataSource` can be in your Data Access Layer.
2. Instead of passing instance of `IDataSource`/`DataSource` you can pass a function (e.g. [anonymous function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function)).
3. Instead of passing instance of `IDataSource`/`DataSource` into constructor you can pass instance of `Data`. In order to implement lazy load derived type from `Data` can be used (e.g. `LazyData` that implemented in Data Access). Sometimes `LazyData` type is implemented like [decorator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern).

These links might be helpful:

1. [Lazy Loading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_loading)
2. [Four Ways to Implement Lazy Loading in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/620215/Four-Ways-to-Implement-Lazy-Loading-in-Csharp)